# How can I reduce code duplication when iterating through RGB colors?

Tags: python, loops, colors, iteration, rgb

I wrote a script to iterate through the 3 RGB values with pre-set increments.

You'll notice a copy/paste of six loops with a change in each one.

I imagine these six sections could be combined into one or two parent loops to increment through one child loop instead of 6. Does that make sense?

My goal is to reduce the size of this code.

Here is the code:

```
color_numbers = [0,255]
increment_between_values = [64,64,63,64]

r_val=[]
g_val=[]
b_val=[]
rgb_values=[]#FORMAT: 255,255,255

def color_function():
    color_base_b = color_numbers[0]
    color_top_g = color_numbers[1]
    color_base_r = color_numbers[0]

    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)):
        r_val.append(color_numbers[0])
        g_val.append(color_numbers[1])
        color_base_b += increment_between_values[x]
        b_val.append(color_base_b)
        
    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)): 
        r_val.append(color_numbers[0])
        color_top_g -= increment_between_values[x]
        g_val.append(color_top_g)
        b_val.append(color_base_b)
            
    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)): 
        color_base_r += increment_between_values[x]
        r_val.append(color_base_r)
        g_val.append(color_top_g)
        b_val.append(color_base_b)
            
    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)): 
        r_val.append(color_base_r)
        g_val.append(color_top_g)
        color_base_b -= increment_between_values[x]
        b_val.append(color_base_b)
            
    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)): 
        r_val.append(color_base_r)
        color_top_g += increment_between_values[x]
        g_val.append(color_top_g)
        b_val.append(color_base_b)
            
    for x in range(len(increment_between_values)): 
        color_base_r -= increment_between_values[x]
        r_val.append(color_base_r)
        g_val.append(color_top_g)
        b_val.append(color_base_b)  
            
    for t in range(len(r_val)):
        print(str(r_val[t])+","+str(g_val[t])+","+str(b_val[t]))

color_function()
```

From what I see, the change in each loop goes as follows:
loop 1: initial value
loop 2: initial value
loop 3: increment up
loop 4: top value
loop 5: top value
loop 6: increment down

These six steps are offset for each of the R,G and B
For example: When R is on loop 1, G is on loop 3, and B is on loop 5.
There is a second loop that switches from + to - (increment up, increment down)

I hope I've explained this clearly
The code works as is, I'd just like to understand how it could be optimized.

Comment: Working code should be posted on Code Review.

Comment: i suggest you generate rgb codes from hsl, then run through hsl and just generate all hsl values

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/generate-colors-in-javascript/

Comment: Please say what you are actually trying to achieve rather than saying you want to iterate through something 6 times in some steps. Are you trying to reduce the number of colours? How? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable names are distractingly long, misleading, and used inconsistently. And the looping by index is bad. A suggestion:

```
def color_function():
    r = b = color_numbers[0]
    g = color_numbers[1]

    def append():
        r_val.append(r)
        g_val.append(g)
        b_val.append(b)

    for inc in increment_between_values:
        b += inc
        append()
        
    # the other five loops similarly...

    for rgb in zip(r_val, g_val, b_val):
        print(*rgb, sep=",")
```

Still six loops, but much shorter/clearer, easy to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that there are only one 0, one 255, and another thing that iterates upward if it starts from 0, downward if it starts from 255

```
def mycf():
    c=[0,0,0] # Starting point
    l=[0,64,128,192,255] # Possible values
    res=[] # Result
    for p0 in range(3): # Where is 0 in c 
        c[p0]=0
        for p255 in range(3): # Where in 255 in c
            if p255==p0: continue # Cannot be where is 0
            c[p255]=255
            pother=3-p0-p255 # Where is the other value (sum p0+p255+pother = 0+1+2 (in another order) = 3. So 3-p0-p255 is the pother)
            if c[pother]!=l[0]: l=l[::-1] # Iterates possible value from where we are. That is either 0 or 255. So if we are not at l[0], reverse it
            # The if is for clarity. In fact we could have started with l=[255,192,128,64,0] and reverted each times inconditionnaly
            for x in l[1:]:
                c[pother]=x
                res.append(list(c))
    return res
```

### Itertools yoga

If you really want to reduce the number of lines of code, we can do a one-liner (but a big line) with some itertools yoga

```py
import itertools
def listRgb(*p):
    return list(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2)))))

listRgb(0,64,128,192,255)
```

Explanation:

`itertools.permutations([0,255,x])` are all combinations of 0,255 and x, in a deterministic order (0,255,x), (0,x,255), (255,0,x), ... Or to be more accurate it is an iterator going through those triplets (6 of them)

So `(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])` is an iterator going through all those iterators for x being any of 4 values 64,128,192,255. So if we were to unroll this "iterators of iterators" we would get 4 sequences of  6 sequences of triplets.

So `zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:]))` returns quadruplets made of one elements of each of those sequences. So an iterator of quadruplets of triplets. 6 of them. Corresponding for each possible permulation of 0, 255 and x, and each x values of a triplet. In ascending order for x. We are almost there. Except, that we wanted to have them in descending order half of the times.

`zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1]))` is that same thing in descending order

Note that the first one skip the 0 (that is redundant with the last of previous iteration), while the second skip the 255 (likewise).

So we are interested in half of those 4-sequence in the first one (the ascending one) and half in the second one.

We can slice one of 2 with `islice`

`itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2)` Keeps the ascending sequences
`itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2)` the descending ones

We can picks one from each other of those halves (which is a way of alternating from where we pick the sequences) with zip

`zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2))`

Almost there.
Since what we have here is pairs (from the last zip) of 4-uplets of triplets ; 3 of them, that is a triplet of pairs of 4-uplets of triplets (or, to be accurate, iterator that would compute that if we were iterating it. For now, we haven't done any computation. It is just an iterator), we need to concatenate the result. Since the whole point of itertools is to keep things as iterator (to not use any memory or cpu before the time we really iterates things), rather that converting that to list and concatenating them, I use `chain` that will iterate each of the 3 pairs one after the other, to get a  6-uplet,

So `itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2)))` is an iterator, iterating through 6 4-uplets of triplets. Again, we would like to just iterate the triplets. So, `chain` again

`itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2))))` is the final iterator. The one whose values are the triplets

In fact, it should be what my function returns (instead of returning `list` of that). Because list would create the whole list. And maybe you just want to enumerate those colors one after each other, without necessary keeping them in memory. The `list` I add in my function is just to demonstrate. But your question is `iterate`, so no need to build a list.

For example

```py
import itertools
def itRgb(*p):
    return itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2))))

for r,g,b in itRgb(*range(256)):
   print(r,g,b)
```

Prints the 1530 values with step 1, without ever building a list of those values

So,

### tl;dr,

you can iterate the color with the one-liner:

```
p=[0,64,128,192,255]
for r,g,b in itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*zip(itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[1:])),0,None,2),itertools.islice(zip(*(itertools.permutations([0,255,x]) for x in p[-2::-1])),1,None,2)))):
    print(r,g,b)
```

Comment: Usually the goal of shorter code is to make it easier to understand, not harder.

Comment: @MarkRansom I never said it was a good idea. I don't even think it is a good idea. But I am not the one who asked for "shorter code" and not for "easier to understand code" :D

Comment: @MarkRansom if it were for me, I would use tools that already perform this kind of tasks. For example `m=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('m', [(0,2,0), (0,0,2),(2,0,0),(0,2,0)], N=10000)` and then `np.round(m(np.linspace(0.042,1,24))*255)[:,:3]`. Not exactly the same exact values. But, well, it does iterate through that rainbow of RGB. I am even pretty sure there is already such a colormap in the predefined colormaps of `matplotlib`. But that wasn't the question.